# Exchange Online Resource Permissions for Organisation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, exchange

Good Morning,

Hopefully this has not already been asked as I cannot see a thread about it.

My company has just been migrated over to Exchange Online and we have 2 meeting rooms available as resources to the company.

However, when booking there rooms through desktop outlook software they can only see "Busy" on any meetings or appointments on the resource.

Is there any way you can change the internal organisation permissions for the resource to allow people to see Full Details?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a combination of a permissions issue *and* a by-design function of Exchange resource calendars where they automatically strip the details of the meeting when adding it to the room calendar.

There are some configuration options that will allow users to see more details, but unfortunately they are not available in either the Office 365 Admin console or the Exchange  admin center. They can only be set using remote PowerShell. As a new Office 365 admin you will soon come to learn this is true for a large number of configuration options in Office 365, so now is the time to start learning about remote PowerShell if you are not already familiar.

Firstly, I recommend installing and configuring the latest version of the Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module. Microsoft have a detailed guide for that here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

*(It is possible to start a remote PowerShell session to Exchange Online without the module, and you will no doubt come across guides online that do this, but the module allows you to authenticate with an account using MFA, which I strongly recommend).*

That's honestly the harder part of the process. Once you have a successful PowerShell connection to Exchange Online, the actual commands you need are relatively straightforward:

First, let's get a list of all your room mailboxes:

```
$allRooms = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox
```

Verify that this worked by displaying the list in table form:

```
$allRooms | Format-Table
```

Now we can use the [Set-MailboxFolderPermission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps) command to set the default view permissions for all your resource calendars to **LimitedDetails** (you can change it to **FullAccess** if you really want, but that alone won't get you much other than a headache when you realize any user can now delete meetings from the room calendar).

```
$allRooms | ForEach {Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($_.alias):\Calendar" -User default -AccessRights "LimitedDetails"}
```

That's the permissions done, but the details still won't show. We need to tell Exchange to stop stripping the meeting details from the entry in the resource calendar using the [Set-CalendarProcessing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps) command:

```
$allRooms | Set-CalendarProcessing -DeleteSubject $false -DeleteComments $false
```

If you don't want to show the text of the message body of the meeting, leave off the **-DeleteComments $false** parameter (which is what I did in our environment).

Bear in mind that the **Set-CalendarProcessing** command only affects new meetings made after the command was issued: your existing meetings are already stripped of these details and you can't retroactively restore them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the default permission on the resource mailbox calendar. J. Schlackman provided a detailed action with PowerShell commands.

In another way, you could assign an account with “Full Access” permission in the resource mailbox “mailbox delegation” page; launch this account with Outlook client, and open the resource mailbox calendar, “properties” – “permissions” – “Default”, change to other permission level.

If you use the latest O365 Outlook version, you may see “My Organization” instead of “Default” in permission page.